# How insert a navbar inside a <textarea> or any other element?

Tags: html, css, textarea

If I have a css like that:

```
  .navbar {
    grid-area: header;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }

  .navbar ul li {
    display: inline;
  }

  .navbar ul li a {
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .navbar ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

I can add a navbar to the top of the page:

```
  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">teste1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">teste2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">teste3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

How I could the same, but with the navbar inside a element like a `<textarea>`?

```
<textarea name="name" rows="25" cols="80">
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><<a href="#">teste1</a>/li>
      <li><<a href="#">teste2</a>/li>
      <li><<a href="#">teste3</a>/li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</textarea>
```

I try the code above, but when I visualize the page in the browser, the code is displayed inside tne textarea, instead of show the navbar.

Comment: is there an element which this is possible? I mean, the outer element have a fixed size, for instance 640x480, and inside it a navbar with a behavior like the one above?

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Certainly you can have a div with a navbar at the top...that's basic HTML but It's really unclear what it is you are trying to do

Comment: Something like this perhaps - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/NWWJmbZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's true that you can't nest an element within an actual `textarea` element, that doesn't mean the task as described isn't capable of being accomplished, simply look at the `textarea` you type answers in here with.

What I recommend for your goal is to create a wrapper `div` (let's call it `textarea-with-nav`), insert your nav-bar and a `textarea` into that `div`, and style it that way. Below you will find a minimal example of this with the resize disabled.

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
.primary-content {
 padding-top: 55px;
}
.navbar {
 grid-area: header;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #333;
 width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
}
.navbar.site-nav {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
}
.navbar ul { list-style-type: none; }
.navbar ul li { display: inline; }
.navbar ul li a {
 color: white;
 padding: 8px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar ul li a:hover {
 background-color: #555;
 color: white;
 height: 100%;
}
.textarea-with-nav {
        transform: translate(50%);
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
 position: realtive;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.textarea-with-nav > .navbar {
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.textarea-with-nav > textarea {
 border: none;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 width: 396px !important;
 height: 246px !important;
 resize: none;
}
.textarea-with-nav > textarea:focus { outline: none; }
```

```html
<div class="navbar site-nav">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">teste1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">teste2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">teste3</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div class="primary-content">
 <div class="textarea-with-nav">
  <div class="navbar">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">teste1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">teste2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">teste3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed feugiat lacus nisi, eu pretium mi lacinia tempor. Nullam sit amet congue justo. Pellentesque non enim volutpat, vestibulum lacus sed, lacinia est. Duis tempus tincidunt lectus non cursus. Vestibulum tempor, velit sit amet ullamcorper congue, nisl urna consequat sem, eu fringilla tellus lorem suscipit lectus. Integer vel scelerisque dolor. Praesent vulputate diam laoreet auctor tristique. Curabitur venenatis odio tincidunt felis elementum, eu lobortis elit fringilla. Vestibulum lacus arcu, euismod ut lobortis sit amet, vehicula sit amet massa. Etiam quis enim et arcu ullamcorper ullamcorper. In eu lacus dolor. Fusce at vestibulum sapien. Etiam at nisl ut purus molestie euismod vel et urna.

Fusce maximus arcu eget diam efficitur, ut dignissim ipsum ultrices. Duis est magna, dapibus vel pharetra vitae, tincidunt et ligula. Nam dapibus blandit nisi, eget ultricies magna tempor ac. Proin euismod, ipsum quis malesuada mollis, magna libero elementum nisl, et ullamcorper enim nulla vitae lectus. Nulla facilisi. Etiam at aliquam justo. Cras ut sollicitudin eros. Nam vitae sapien commodo, condimentum justo aliquam, sodales justo. Maecenas eu odio placerat, tincidunt lectus non, dapibus felis. Aliquam in cursus dui, sed dictum lectus. Phasellus tincidunt facilisis gravida. Donec augue mauris, elementum id lobortis sed, commodo vel metus. Sed sit amet sollicitudin diam.</textarea>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your example is just what I need, but I not being able to resize the textarea. What I could change in the code above to allow this?

Comment: @KleberMota simply locate and remove the line that says “resize: none”. You’ll also have to adapt the container if you want it to expand with the text area, but this is a good start.

Comment: Ok, I just didi that, I can resize the textarea now, but the navbar do not follow the changes on the width. Is there a way to make the navbar resize when the textarea is resized?

Comment: @KleberMota As I stated above: *You’ll also have to adapt the container if you want it to expand with the text area*. If you're having trouble with that part, feel free to post another question for further help as it is another issue entirely.

Comment: Ok, I already did; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58994464/resize-2-elements-simultaneously